# Must disconnect then reconnect to wifi otherwise it times out

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, network, wifi, mojave

My MacBook Pro, Mid-2015 w/ Retina Display, running macOS Mojave 10.14.6, very very frequently times out when it tries to load web pages.

It says it's still connected to the wifi network, but the only way to load the page is to disconnect and then reconnect to (the same) wifi.

Then it will work fine for at least a few minutes, before I invariably run into the same problem again.

Comment: Did you try to reset your network devices like your modem, router, switch,...? Is the signal OK?

Comment: @DaktaMoriamé doesn't happen on any other device in the house, and yes